# Accessing Context inside an ExchangeFilterFunction

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

For some reason a [context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) inside the `doAfterSuccessOrError` method is not available (populated) from the upstream. I've tried to access it using `Mono.subscriberContext()` (see the snipped). I would expect to have it present but for some reason is not. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class LoggingRequestExchangeFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return next.exchange(request).doAfterSuccessOrError((res, ex) -> {
            Mono.subscriberContext().map((ctx -> {
                log.info("doAfterSuccessOrError Context {}",ctx);
                // log req/res ...
                return ctx;
            })).subscribe();

        }).subscriberContext( ctx -> {
            log.info("SubscriberContext: {}" , ctx);
            return ctx;
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a log output

```
23:16:59.426  INFO [reactor-http-epoll-2] .p.c.LoggingRequestExchangeFunction [] SubscriberContext: Context1{nexmo-tracing-context=TracingContext{{traceId=f04961da-933a-4d1d-85d5-3bea2c47432f, clientIp=N/A}}}
23:16:59.589  INFO [reactor-http-epoll-2] .p.c.LoggingRequestExchangeFunction [] doAfterSuccessOrError Context Context0{}
```

Comment: why do you `.subscribe()` in your application? the subscriber is the calling client, that is probably your problem.

Comment: It is just an example in an real app of course I don't.

Comment: please post your real code then and not an "example"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you create a new Mono inside `doAfterSuccessOrError` which is independent from the original reactor chain since you subscribe to it separately.

If you just want to log something inside, your alternative is to use [`doOnEach`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) operator which beside the signal type gives you access to the context as well.

```java
Mono.just("hello")
    .doOnEach((signal) ->
            {
                if (signal.isOnError() || signal.isOnComplete())
                {
                    Context ctx = signal.getContext();

                    log.info("doAfterSuccessOrError Context {}",ctx);
                    // log req/res ...
                }
            })
    .subscriberContext( ctx -> {
            log.info("SubscriberContext: {}" , ctx);
            return ctx;
      })
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: You are right. So there is currently no way how to access a context directly in `doAfterSuccessOrError(..)` right?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: you have to understand that the `Context` CANNOT be resolved out of thin air (or in Java, a `ThreadLocal`): resolving the `Context` involves traversing a chain of subscribers (the intermediate ones from the operators that you used) up to the point where it was last written to. `Mono.subscriberContext()` is a bit misleading, it only works inside eg. a `flatMap` because the flatMap will attach it to the outer chain, and it will then be able to see the main sequence's `Context` downstream of it